# AlertDialog on spinner

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I just wanna make alertdialog on selected item spinner. always wrong with this code.`

```
    sh = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.shield);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adaptera = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),
            R.array.shield, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adaptera.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    sh.setAdapter(adaptera);


    sa = (String) sh.getSelectedItem();
    boolean sw = sa.trim().equals("lead");
    sw.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            AlertDialog.Builder bu = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            LayoutInflater d0 = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
            bu.setView(d0.inflate(R.layout.d01, null))
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        }
                    })
                    .show();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

with Custom layout on alertdialog

Comment: use `setOnItemSelectedListener` instead of OnTouch

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **`OnItemSelectedListener`** instead of `OnTouchListener` :

```
 sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            // show alert here

             AlertDialog.Builder bu = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                LayoutInflater d0 = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
                bu.setView(d0.inflate(R.layout.d01, null))
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            }
                        })
                        .show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Hope it helps ツ